# How can I boost::bind an abstract overriden method, so that the child's method is called?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing a base class which has an abstract callback. Like this:

```
class ValueListener
{
public:
    ValueListener();
    void registerPoint(ValuesSource &mgr, bool create=true);
    void valueReceived( QVariant value ) = 0; /* slot */
    QString valueName() = 0;
};
```

The overriding classes shall implement what do they want to do with the received value. But `ValueListener` itself is responsible for registering the callback:

```
void ValueListener::registerPoint( ValuesSource& mgr, bool create ) {
    ValueSourceInfo* info = mgr.getPoint(valueName(), create);
    if(info) {
        // Connect the callback
        info->valueChanged.connect( boost::bind( &ValueListener::valueReceived, this, _1 ) );
    }
}
```

But obviously, neither `this` neither the `&ValueListener::valueReceived` are the things that should be receiving value updates - the overriding class should. So how can I bind the overridden method without knowing it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out doing this is probably a flawed idea. Instead, I created two methods, one normal and one private:

```
class ValueListener
{
public:
    ValueListener();
    void registerPoint(ValuesSource &mgr, bool create=true);
    void valueReceived( QVariant value ) = 0;
    QString valueName() = 0;
private:
    void valueReceivedPrivate( QVariant value ) {valueReceived(value);}; /* slot */
};
```

And I used connect on the private method:

```
void ValueListener::registerPoint( ValuesSource& mgr, bool create ) {
    ValueSourceInfo* info = mgr.getPoint(valueName(), create);
    if(info) {
        // Connect the callback
        info->valueChanged.connect( boost::bind( &ValueListener::valueReceivedPrivate, this, _1 ) );
    }
```